# SQL request 3 linked tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, request, linked-tables

I have 3 Tables:

[image: Linked tables]

And i want this result:

[image: result]

I try with order by but, it did not work,
Someone have an idea

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: What did you actually try? Can you post the exact SQL statement you used?

Answer (score 1):

You can do an `INNER JOIN` with `GROUP BY`, e.g.:

```
SELECT s.number AS supplier, c.category AS category, s.date as `date`, COUNT(r.*)
AS total
FROM supplier s JOIN register r ON s.id = r.supplier_id
JOIN category c ON c.id = r.category_id
GROUP BY s.number, c.category, s.date;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the Linked Server name is [LinkedSample\Tables]
Then you can use the code below:

```
SELECT s.number AS supplier, c.category AS category, s.date as `date`, COUNT(r.*) AS total
FROM  [LinkedSample\Tables].supplier s 
JOIN [LinkedSample\Tables].register r ON s.id = r.supplier_id 
JOIN [LinkedSample\Tables].category c ON c.id = r.category_id
GROUP BY s.number, c.category, s.date;
```